# post request with passing list in body using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

i have created spring boot api and now i am integrating it with android app in post request i pass a list while testing from postman and it worked well but it did not work while i send list from android. please tell me how to send a list in a body of json with volley library [this is image of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHIIR.png)

this is my code

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
List<Integer> ids=new ArrayList<>();
ids.add(11);
ids.add(12);
jsonBody.put("ids",ids);
final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ADD_SKILLS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {


        Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
    }
}, error -> Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString())) {
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString = "";
        if (response != null) {

            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

        }
        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
};

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are passing wrong json format to post API like below.

```
{
  "ids": "[11, 12]"
}
```

but in postman you are passing jsonarray ids in object.

```
{ 
  "ids":[11,12]
}
```

so make change in your code like this

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

JSONArray jArrIds=new JSONArray();
jArrIds.put(11);
jArrIds.put(12);
jsonBody.put("ids",jArrIds);
```